# Problem wiht multiple listviews inside column / Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height

Tags: flutter, listview, bloc

I am still new to flutter and trying to achieve a following layout of two listviews, one is displaying the top news articles, another one is showing further articles. The first one is supposed to be horizontal, the second one vertical, but both are element of one single scrollview.

Something like this here:

[image]

I am using cubit to have different states, while it loads the articles, but in combination with the SingleChildScrollView, I can never get the second, vertical listview to display, I always get
"Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height."

How can i fix this?

Also, if two widgets share the same list fetched by a bloc, is there a good way to reuse that list, instead of having two BlocBuilders?

Here is my code:

body.dart

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget buildArticleWidgets(List<Article> articles) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      primary: false,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ArticleWidget(articles[index]);
      },
      itemCount: 5,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSmallArticleWidgets(List<Article> articles) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      primary: false,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return SmallArticle(articles[index]);
      },
      itemCount: 5,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final articleCubit = context.bloc<ArticlesCubit>();

    articleCubit.getArticles();

    return Column(
      children: [
        CategoriesTab(),
        Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text('Popular News',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 18,
                  )),
            ),
            SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                child: BlocBuilder<ArticlesCubit, ArticlesState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is ArticlesInitial) {
                      return Container();
                    } else if (state is ArticlesLoading) {
                      return Container();
                    } else if (state is ArticlesLoaded) {
                      return buildArticleWidgets(state.articles);
                    }
                    return Container();
                  },
                )),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text('More News',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 18,
                  )),
            ),
            BlocBuilder<ArticlesCubit, ArticlesState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is ArticlesInitial) {
                      return Container();
                    } else if (state is ArticlesLoading) {
                      return Container();
                    } else if (state is ArticlesLoaded) {
                      return _buildSmallArticleWidgets(state.articles);
                    }
                    return Container();
                  },
                )
          ],
        )))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

home_screen.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/menu.svg"),
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              },
              tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
            );
          },
        ),
        title: Text(
          'NewsLab',
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Body(),
    );
  }
}
```

and

main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "NewsLab",
      theme: ThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          primaryColor: Colors.blue,
          textTheme:
              Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(bodyColor: Colors.transparent),
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
      home: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => ArticlesCubit(ArticlesRepository()),
        child: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second Column widget in your body, use Expanded widget on the children widgets.

Comment: hey, when i try that, I get this error:

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. ....